# Reduce code duplication with dynamic if let matching

Tags: rust

I have this code below that is repeated in many places in my application.
The only thing that differs on the per-command basis is the `if let Role { whatever } = role` line

```rust
#[command]
pub async fn protect(ctx: &Context, msg: &Message, mut args: Args) -> CommandResult {
    let target_tag: String = args.single()?;
    let (user_id, guild_id) = msg.get_ids();
    let (target_id, _) = LupusCtxHelper::parse_tag_to_target_id(ctx, Tag(target_tag))
        .await
        .ok_or(MyError)?;

    let player = {
        let dt = ctx.data.read().await;
        dt.get_player(&guild_id, &user_id).await
    };

    if let Some(p) = player {
        // this line is the problem
        if let LupusRole::BODYGUARD { .. } = *p.current_role() {
            LupusCtxHelper::send_lupus_command(ctx, msg, LupusAction::Protect(target_id)).await?
        } else {
            msg.channel_id
                .say(&ctx.http, "check your role dude")
                .await?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

How would you guys suggest I go about cleaning up this code/refactoring in an external function? It seems like I can't pattern match dynamically on the left.
ps: beware that the enum LupusRole has struct values

Example of another file:

```rust
#[command]
pub async fn frame(ctx: &Context, msg: &Message, mut args: Args) -> CommandResult {
    let target_tag: String = args.single()?;
    let (user_id, guild_id) = msg.get_ids();
    let (target_id, _) = LupusCtxHelper::parse_tag_to_target_id(ctx, Tag(target_tag))
        .await
        .ok_or(MyError)?;

    let player = {
        let dt = ctx.data.read().await;
        dt.get_player(&guild_id, &user_id).await
    };

    if let Some(p) = player {
        if let LupusRole::GUFO = *p.current_role() {
            LupusCtxHelper::send_lupus_command(ctx, msg, LupusAction::Frame(target_id)).await?
        } else {
            msg.channel_id
                .say(&ctx.http, "fra... ruolo sbagliato")
                .await?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the whole fn is repeated with the only difference being the `if let`?

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant, the only difference is the Enum variant in the if let and the enum action in the line after the if let (LupusRole and LupusAction)

Comment: The code starting from `}g.channel_id` is broken (probably incorrectly copy&pasted), please fix.

Comment: Add an argument to the function, `is_target_role: Fn(&LupusRole) -> bool`; then instead of the `if let ...  {` you can do `if is_target_role(p.current_role()) {` and you'd invoke the function with a suitable closure, e.g. `|role| matches!(role, LupusRole::BODYGUARD { ... })` or `|role| matches!(role, LupusRole::GUFO)`.

Comment: Tip: You will get a lot more help if you provide a minimal, reproducible example in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Your current code does not compile for others, since a lot of the symbols are unknown.